# how to integrate testrail with selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, integration-testing, testrail

Hi everyone as I am just started to work in testrail and I want to integrate my testrail with selenium using Eclipse
**What I want to do?**
I want to run my test case in selenium and if its pass then my test case in Testrail should pass and else fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a call to TestRail's endpoint *add_result_for_case*.
Example in Java:

```
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("status_id", new Integer(1));
JSONObject r = (JSONObject) client.sendPost("add_result_for_case/1/1", data);
```

You can find the definition of the endpoint [here](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/results#addresultforcase).

You can find the complete documentation [here](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api) and some extra examples of usage [here](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-api).